# Automate a menu presented by a remote SSH jump server

Tags: ssh, openssh

I need to connect to a remote host through a jump server, but this server presents me with a menu like

```
Please make a selection (1 2 ... q)
1. SSH Remote Server
2. Open a local session
q. Exit
```

From the menu, I need to pick (1) and then answer the nex prompt with the address of the remote host:

`Enter the hostname or IP of the server you want to connect to :`

Is it possible to automate this connection using `ssh_config` or do I need to write an `expect` script or similar?

Any better options?

Comment: Have you considered bypassing that menu by running a shell with a command like `ssh -t your_intermediate_server bash -i`?

Comment: If you can use ssh to run random command on the intermediate server, I think the best solution would be to use proxy command, as explained on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/296217/219302 .

Comment: It hadn't occurred to me that I could "escape" the menu, but it seems to be the case. I will explore this path, thank you.

Comment: @user2233709, you were right. I could run a remote command, so I could run `bash` from there and copy pubkeys, and then I could add ProxyJump to my `ssh_config` and jump straight to my destination. Do you want to create an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I just wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you’re asking for “any better option”, it might be possible to bypass the menu on the “jump server”.

An option is that this menu is implemented by your login shell, either because the program **is** your login shell or because it is called **by** your login shell (for instance in your `~/.bash_profile`). In such a situation, you should be able to bypass it by explicitly running a interactive non-login shell as a remote command: `ssh -t jump_server bash -i`.

Even better, the ssh server running on the “jump server” may allow you to do some port forwarding. Then the command `ssh -W remote_host:22 jump_server` makes a connection to the “remote host” on TCP port 22 through an SSH connection to your “jump server”. You can use that to establish an SSH connection from your own computer to the “remote host” through a second SSH connection from your computer to the “jump host” with `ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh -W %h:%p jump_server' remote_host`.

If that works, you may automate things with two lines in your `.ssh/config`:

```
Host remote_host
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p jump_server
```

Then, running `ssh remote_host` will automatically connect you to the “remote host” through the “jump server”.